# Laravel query default 0 if not results found

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a dashboard to show results from a campaign. To do so I have a query like this:

```
$list = DB::table('campaigns')->leftJoin('campaigns_products_results', 'campaigns_products_results.campaign_id', '=', 'campaigns.id');
```

But when there are not results for the campaign, I still want to show 0. For that I use this:

```
$list->select('campaigns.*', DB::raw('(CASE WHEN campaigns_products_results.total_views IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(campaigns_products_results.total_views) END) AS total_views'));
```

Everything works fine so far, but now I would like to add a filter to define a date range for the results. For example, yesterday or 7 days ago. I was thinking about this, but then the query results empty and there will be no data.

```
$list = $list->whereDate('campaigns_products_results.created_at', Carbon::yesterday());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [easy way](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) to do that:

```
->whereBetween('created_at', $date_range)
```

Where **$date_range array** looks like this:

```
[
    "2021-08-23",
    "2021-08-30",
]
```

So you can use something like this:

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [
    (new Carbon)->subDays(7)->startOfDay()->toDateString(),
    (new Carbon)->now()->endOfDay()->toDateString()
])
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. That is not really an answer to my question. The problem is if I add the date filter to my query the results return empty because there are no created results.